# File System Disk Space Usage

Tags: unix, linux-disk-free

When I use the unix `df` command to return the disk usage, I get the following reported

```
/dev/sda1                       30929148 30530112    399036  99% /
```

How get what is using the disk space.

Is there a way to determine as to which directories are taking up space?

Comment: Try running `df -lh` -- might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `du` (disk usage). For example:

```
➜  ~ du -sh /usr/* 2>/dev/null 
587M    /usr/bin
276M    /usr/include
5,4G    /usr/lib
444M    /usr/lib32
0       /usr/lib64
96K     /usr/local
0       /usr/sbin
3,1G    /usr/share
4,0K    /usr/src
```

To sort use `sort -h`.

**Edit**

Works with directories (which can be mountpoints).

```
du -sh $(lsblk -no MOUNTPOINT /dev/sda1)/* 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: so i tried  du -sh  /dev/sda1/* 2>/dev/null.
this returned nothing
The /dev/sda1 is a filesystem. Can the du command be run on filesystem ?

Comment: Thanks ashunt. Unfotunately, the du command does not report anything for me. Would you know of any other commands i can try out to find which directories are consuming the disk space /

Comment: Hi ashunt,
Just tried your last suggestion ( du -sh $(lsblk .. ), and got a list back of what seems to be filenames in order of biggest disk space consumer under the filesystem /dev/sda1.

Is that correct understanding ?

Comment: That list is the disk usage of files and directories in the mountpoint of `/dev/sda1`. I think is what you asked for.

Comment: Hi ashunt
I think this is prefect, I can use your latest ( du -sh $(lsblk .. ) command to identify the directories under /dev/sda1. Than to use ( du -sh /usr .. ) on each directory to understand disk usage under each directory . 
Many thanks for a  really quick resolution on my query.

Comment: @PeteLong if this solved your problem, please mark as solution